# Sending bulk mail using nodemailer without others knowing all recipients?

Tags: javascript, node.js, email, nodemailer, bulk-email

I am trying to build a bulk mailer service which could send campaign emails to all the list of users. Everything works fine, when I import the user emails from json file and add it to `to` section in nodemailer transport object.

Something like this below:-

```
// send mail with defined transport object
const message = {
    from: `${process.env.FROM_NAME} <${process.env.FROM_EMAIL}>`,
    to: options.email,
    subject: options.subject,
    text: options.message,
};
```

Here `options.email` is a array of all emails of registered users. 
Now the problem is, that the received users can see that who else have received the email as CC.
I tried using BCC but I cannot leave `to` object empty. I need a way to send bulk email where receivers won't know who else have got the email.

Please Help and thankyou in advance.

Comment: Have you tried to set your email address to the `To` field and include others to the `BCC` field? Does it work as you need?

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev Yes, I have. But then in the email, they can see my email in `to` field. I want them to think that they are the only one who have received it. I thought of looping through entire array of emails and sending them individually but I don't think that would be efficient considering emails array would be in thousands.